# Why is this the permutation written as the product of disjoint cycles?

Tags: permutations

In my notes, it says that $\sigma = (1 5)(2 4 7 5)(1 4 6)(2 3) = (1 3 2 6)(4 7 5)$

However the answer I get is $\sigma = (1 5)(2 4 7 5)(1 4 6)(2 3) = (1 4 6)(2 3)(7 5)$. What I did was I started with the  smallest element, 1, and worked through the cycles from right to left and saw what each element was mapped to. So $1 \rightarrow 4$ in the third cycle, and $4 \rightarrow 6$. Then $2 \rightarrow 3$ in the last cycle, and all we had left was $4 \rightarrow 7 \rightarrow 5$ in the second cycle.

I know my approach must be incorrect, but it's all I can find when I look through my notes and search online. Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: It seems like the first one has been evaluated *left to right*. It seems to send $1 \to 3,3 \to 2, 2 \to 6, 6 \to 1$, and $ 4 \to 7, 7 \to 5, 5 \to 4$.  Even your computation seems incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually disagree with both you AND the book. The book, it seems, has worked left-to-right instead of right-to-left; you have made an error in your computations.

To read this right-to-left, remember to work cycle-by-cycle:

$1$ is fixed by $(23)$.  It is mapped to $4$ by $(146)$.  $4$ is mapped to $7$ by $(2475)$.  And $7$ is fixed by $(15)$; so, in all, $1\mapsto7$.  Continuing in this way, you can write $(15)(2475)(146)(23)=(17)(23465)$.

Comment: I wouldn't *disagree* with the book for its left-leaning practices :P But to rephrase the OP's specific error: $(146)$ doesn't send $1 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 6$ all in one go; once that cycle gets a turn sending $1 \mapsto 4$, it's done, and you move on to the next one.

Comment: I understand the mistake the pjs36 is talking about, however because of this I'm unsure why Nick Peterson says the 5 is present in (175)?

Comment: Typo. :-)  Should be $(17)(23465)$.  I'll correct that.